# SQL Server Security Permissions issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-connection, ssms

I have a strange issue when trying login to my WPF application I published. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016, I am also a Server admin. I have a Database called Project Tracking in the server. When trying to log in I am able to login just fine. When another user tries to login they get this error: The underlying provider could not be opened.

Now, if I add them as system admins to the SQL server they are able to login just fine no errors. Although this is not what I want to do for obvious security reasons. How do I go about actually adding them for read/write access to the database?

**The connection string in the application is:** "metadata=res://*/Model.ProjectTracking.csdl|res://*/Model.ProjectTracking.ssdl|res://*/Model.ProjectTracking.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=EPLANDB\PROD4W;initial catalog=ProjectTrackingDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

This is my first go around using SSMS and SQL Servers, so not sure what exactly the problem is or how to word it correctly, I hope I gave enough information if someone could point me the right direction.

Here is a picture of my setup on SSMS. 
[image: SSMS Environment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I found this article over the subject and it worked for me.

1. I had to go into Security for the **Server** right click **Logins** and hit New -> Login.

[image]

2. Your are then brought to this screen. Click Search...

[image]

3. Not sure if this part matters. But I clicked **Object Types** and checked the **Groups**.
4. Add the username you want to include. Make sure to include the domain name.

[image]

5. Click User Mapping.
6. Check Your Database.
7. Make sure to check data reader and data writer and any other roles you would like to include.

[image]

Here is where I found the solution.

[Answer to Problem](https://esha.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202977089-Granting-Access-to-Additional-Users-with-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-for-Genesis-Food-and-Food-Processor)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18941406)

Comment: @EJoshuaS fixed